# Asynchronous Requests not working with Tomcat 7 / Terracotta 3.6

Tags: java, tomcat7, terracotta

I'm working on a Tomcat 7 web application that includes an asynchronous call using a  DeferredResponse object.

All was fine until we introduced Terracotta into the mix for session sharing in our cluster. I'm now getting this in our Catalina logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and
for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code
using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to
servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.
```

We've used the  tag throughout out configuration and this has done the job, right until the TerracottaTomcat70xSessionValve valve was introduced to the Tomcat context.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.terracotta.session.TerracottaTomcat70xSessionValve" tcConfigUrl="[config-url]" />
</Context>
```

What I'm looking for is how to configure the Terracotta Session Valve to support asynchronous requests?

Answer (score 1):

I had a silimar problem. Try add parameter asyncSupported="true" in tag Valve. In my case it had worked.

```
<Context>
<Valve className="org.terracotta.session.TerracottaTomcat70xSessionValve" asyncSupported="true" tcConfigUrl="[config-url]" />
```

Comment: I tried that to no avail, which version of Terracotta are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you use tomcat-redis-session-manager-1.2-tomcat-7-1.2.jar
Please modify the conf support async.

example:

```
<Valve className="com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionHandlerValve" asyncSupported="true" />
<Manager className="com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionManager"
         host="localhost" 
         port="6379" 
         database="0" 
         maxInactiveInterval="60" />
```